# Bind and fetch dropdown list value in typescript and Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select

This question was asked many times and couldn't help me with my problem. Not sure whats wrong with the approach and hope some fresh "eyes"

Here is my dropdownlist binding in HTML: I am binding programName which is a string to both value and text properties.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedObject">
   <option *ngFor="let p of programs" value= {{p.programName}}>
         {{p.programName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

In my .ts file, here is the what i am doing to bind the default value to the "select"

```
 loadData(pList: IProgram[]) {
    this.programs = pList;
    if (this.programs.length > 0) {
        this.selectedObject = this.programs[0];
    }
}
```

The data is binding to "select"
properly,

- but the default value is showing as empty text, where i need to click and select an value.
- Another issue is when i change the dropdown value from A to B, the "selectedObject" value is always giving me "A" instead of "B". As it is [ngModel], two way binding would take care. But, its not happening as i might be missing something here.

Can someone help whats the problem with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">
   <option *ngFor="let p of programs" 
           [ngValue] = "p"
           [selected]="p.programName == selectedObject.programName"
          >
         {{p.programName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Check this [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/mw3sSmd0U1grEgZ9PaJW?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: No, it didn't work with this fix. Even after this, the default value is empty and changed value was still showing as first value "A" instead of "B".

Comment: @Born2Code Ah, value binding was off too, it should be [value] = "p", rather than value= {{p.programName}}, Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Madhu. That fixed my first issue of defaulting the value instead of empty selection.   The second issue still exists, I was doing below code to load the selected value                                                                       getmyData() {
        this._myService.getPayments(this.selectedObject.programName)
            .subscribe(pl => this.loadmyData(pl),
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => this.showLoader = false);
    }

Comment: Updated Plunker, use `ngValue` instead.

Comment: Thanks again ! I have updated the plunker and validated, with this <h3>selected value: {{selectedObject.programName}}</h3> and still see the selected value as A when selected with "B". Wondering if (onChange) needs to be added? In other case, it should not as the binding already exists.

Comment: what the link of your Plunker?

Comment: Ah, () is missing in the plunk, see the updated one, http://plnkr.co/edit/111XuH?p=preview

Comment: oh man... such a silly thing i forgot and keep running behind this :( Thanks very much Madhu and appreciate your help here :)

Comment: Hi Madhu, as the model was not binding with missing (), that's the root cause for not binding as well. So, removed [selected] as well and able to bind properly. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the problem is when declaring [ngModel]. It should be within [(ngModel)] which was missed in my original problem. :)

Thanks a lot to Madhu Ranjan for help on the fix !

After correcting (ngModel) able to bind and fetch successfully.

`<select [**(ngModel)**]="selectedObject"><option *ngFor="let p of   programs"value= {{p.programName}}>{{p.programName}}</option>
</select>`